# Knockout custom binding extending the "IF" binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, custom-binding

I have the following custom binding based on Ryan Niemeyer's blog but I was it doesn't work. Instead of fading him the div just doesn't show at all. I tried adding the "init" function but that did not resolve the issue so I went back to just the simple update function like Ryan has it in the example.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeInIf = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.if.update(element, valueAccessor);
        $(element).fadeIn(); 
    } 
};
```

in the html I do the following:

```
<div data-bind="fadeInIf: show">...</div>
```

Blog post: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html

Answer (score 0):

The `if` binding you are proxying to in your `fadeInIf` is actually used for creating dom elements, see [this documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) for details.

To achieve a fadeInIf you simple need.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeInIf = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            $(element).fadeIn();
        }
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/3rRUQ/2/

If what you want is more of a fadeVisible binding I have included an example of that also in the fiddle.

Hope this helps.